# c++: vector of user-defined type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, dynamic

I have a vector that I'm storing data in. I want users to be able to decide the level of precision for the storage vector (either floats or doubles).

How do I declare a vector based on user input? This obviously doesn't work:

```
std::vector<userWantsFloats ? float : double> data; ...
```

Comment: Once you have such a class, how do you intend to put data into it? What do you expect that code to look like?

Comment: Sounds like you want to pass the type as a template argument.

Comment: Why do you want the user to make this decision ?  Is there any reason not to use `double` all the time ?

Comment: @SidS I'm storing billions of floats/doubles and want the user to be able to choose the ability to sacrifice precision for memory.

Comment: @SidS What else do you want me to elaborate upon?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot choose the type used in a class template instantiation based on a value that is known only at run time.

Use of

```
std::vector<userWantsFloats ? float : double> data;
```

is OK if the value of `userWantsFloats` is known at compile time. It is not OK if the value of `userWantsFloats` is not known only at run time.

You'll have to use something along the lines of:

```
if ( userWantsFloats )
{
   std::vector<float> data;
   // Use data
}
else
{
   std::vector<double> data;
   // Use data
}
```

To be able to maximize reuse of rest of your code, they have to be function templates and/or class templates.

```
template <typename T>
void myAppLogic(std::vector<T>& data)
{
   // Do the work of your application
}

if ( userWantsFloats )
{
   std::vector<float> data;
   myAppLogic(data);
}
else
{
   std::vector<double> data;
   myAppLogic(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) option could be to use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

```
std::variant<std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>> data;
```

You then initialize the variant based on user input, but can write any logic only once by using [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

```
std::visit([](auto&& vec) {
  // Do your thing
}, data);
```

If C++17 is not an option, then boost has a variant template that inspired the now standard one. You can use that instead. Consult the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/variant.html) on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately neither boost nor c++17 are usable for this project. Thank you for the explanation, I'll save it in case c++17 eventually becomes an option.

Comment: std::any is perhaps better

Comment: @Michael - How? Using `std::any` means you'd need to manage a type switch yourself everywhere and duplicate logic. It's not what it's meant for.